# Using multiprocessing to speed up filling of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, multiprocessing

I am trying to solve a problem that involves minimizing a certain function. The function contains a numpy array whose elements are filled by calling a function. The array generation is taking a huge amount of time, and I mean that. The array that I'm generating is defined below

```
def cov_p(Phi, l_mat, s_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, N_p):
    ans = np.zeros([N_p, N_p, 2, 2], dtype=complex)
    for i in range(N_p):
        for j in range(N_p):
            ans[i][j] = np.linalg.multi_dot([L_0, R_final(
                Phi, l_mat, s_f, (i-j)*tstep), L_0.T])+np.array([[sigma_11, 0], [0, sigma_22]])*I(i, j)

    return ans.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(2*N_p, -1)
```

where L_0 and I are defined below

```
L_0 = np.eye(2)


def I(m, p):
    if m == p:
        return 1
    return 0
```

As can be seen , each element references the function R_final, which basically returns a 2 by 2 complex matrix. Then I concatenate all those 2 by 2 matrices to form a matrix of size 2N_p by 2N_p. R_final is defined below.

```
def R_x(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j):
    real_integral = quad(S_xr, -np.inf, np.inf,
                         args=(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j), limit=10000)
    imag_integral = quad(S_xc, -np.inf, np.inf,
                         args=(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j), limit=10000)
    return real_integral[0]+1j*imag_integral[0]

def R_final(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t):
    return np.array([[R_x(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j) for j in range(2)] for i in range(2)])
```

where S_xr, S_xc are shown below

```
def S_xr(omega, Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j):
    h_x = np.real(np.linalg.multi_dot(
        [Phi, np.linalg.inv(-1j*omega*np.linalg.inv(l_mat)+np.eye(np.shape(l_mat)[0])), Phi.T]))   #Taking only the real value. Check again!!!

    ans = np.exp(1j*omega*t)*np.linalg.multi_dot([np.conjugate(h_x), s_f, h_x.T])
    return np.real(ans[i][j])

def S_xc(omega, Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j):
    h_x = np.real(np.linalg.multi_dot(
        [Phi, np.linalg.inv(-1j*omega*np.linalg.inv(l_mat)+np.eye(np.shape(l_mat)[0])), Phi.T]))   #Taking only the real value. Check again!!!

    ans = np.exp(1j*omega*t)*np.linalg.multi_dot([np.conjugate(h_x), s_f, h_x.T])
    return np.imag(ans[i][j])
```

Try calculating cov_p for the following values of listed parameters.

```
phi = np.array([[-0.0529255 +0.00662948j, -0.0529255 -0.00662948j,
        -0.03050694-0.00190298j, -0.03050694+0.00190298j],
       [-0.04149906+0.00171591j, -0.04149906-0.00171591j,
         0.01974404-0.00194719j,  0.01974404+0.00194719j]])
lamb_mat = np.array([[-1.00390867 +6.28783994j,  0.         +0.j        ,
         0.         +0.j        ,  0.         +0.j        ],
       [ 0.         +0.j        , -1.00390867 -6.28783994j,
         0.         +0.j        ,  0.         +0.j        ],
       [ 0.         +0.j        ,  0.         +0.j        ,
        -0.25859133+12.09860357j,  0.         +0.j        ],
       [ 0.         +0.j        ,  0.         +0.j        ,
         0.         +0.j        , -0.25859133-12.09860357j]])
S_f = np.array([[100,0],[0,100]])
tstep = 0.1
sigma_11 = 0.3
sigma_22 = 0.4
#Try finding cov_p for the following set of inputs
cov_p(phi, lamb_mat, S_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, 10)
```

What I want to ask is how I can speed up filling of cov_p by dividing the operation into multiple processes.
It's actually the R_final matrices to the right and bottom of cov_p which are taking time.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an example a valid input (possibly random arrays) including the your function calls. If possible, please please choose an example that is typically a bit slow/realistic.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in the code you've shown where cov_p is invoked. Maybe you forgot to post a significant part of your execution flow. What is *quad*? Where is *tstep* defined?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've added all the relevant information in the question. Hope this evaluation of cov_p could be sped up.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Actually, I invoke cov_p in a different function which is the objective function for a minimization problem. Believe me, the code didn't even finish running in 6 days.  And quad is basically scipy.integrate.quad.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parallelize the outermost loop using `Pool` of multiprocessing. The idea is to split the `ans` array in the last dimension and merge it once each part has been computed. Note that the `tstep` variable needs to be sent to processes. Here is the resulting code containing mainly the modified parts:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from multiprocessing import Pool

# [...] -- Code of the following unchanged function here
# I, R_x, R_final, S_xr, S_xc

def cov_p_work(params):
    Phi, l_mat, s_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, N_p, tstep, i = params
    ans = np.zeros([N_p, 2, 2], dtype=complex)
    L_0 = np.eye(2)
    for j in range(N_p):
        ans[j] = np.linalg.multi_dot([L_0, R_final(
            Phi, l_mat, s_f, (i-j)*tstep), L_0.T])+np.array([[sigma_11, 0], [0, sigma_22]])*I(i, j)
    return ans

def cov_p(Phi, l_mat, s_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, N_p, tstep):
    with Pool() as p:
        params = [(Phi, l_mat, s_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, N_p, tstep, i) for i in range(N_p)]
        result = p.map(cov_p_work, params)
    ans = np.array(result)
    return ans.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(2*N_p, -1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # [...] -- Unchanged parameters here

    #Try finding cov_p for the following set of inputs
    cov_p(phi, lamb_mat, S_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, 10, tstep)
```

On my 6-core machine, this is about **5 times faster** (96.9 seconds --> 20.9 seconds). Note that it barely scale with more core since `N_p` is quite small here (which can cause some imperfect load balancing).

Comment: Unfortunately, this implementation is far slower. In fact, I ran the same code in a jupyter notebook cell and left it for more than half an hour before interrupting the kernel. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Did you run *exactly* this code? AFAIK, multiprocessing reexecute the main code of your scrip except the part in the main. This part is mandatory. Having many import can slow the processing. Furthermore, the process can freeze/hang-on if there is any error. Note that it should not last for more than few minutes... So I guess there is an error somewhere happening

Answer (score 0):

The only potential optimisation I see here is to run a wrapper around *quad* as a discrete process. This is because *quad* calls S_xr and S_xc so you can't really optimise those functions.

With the values you've shown, the entire program runs in less than 50 seconds on my machine. How it ran for 6 days on your machine is a mystery. Perhaps you're using different parameters to those shown in your question. Anyway, here's the reworked version in its entirety:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from multiprocessing import Pool

phi = np.array([[-0.0529255 + 0.00662948j, -0.0529255 - 0.00662948j,
                 -0.03050694-0.00190298j, -0.03050694+0.00190298j],
                [-0.04149906+0.00171591j, -0.04149906-0.00171591j,
                 0.01974404-0.00194719j,  0.01974404+0.00194719j]])
lamb_mat = np.array([[-1.00390867 + 6.28783994j,  0. + 0.j,
                      0. + 0.j,  0. + 0.j],
                     [0. + 0.j, -1.00390867 - 6.28783994j,
                      0. + 0.j,  0. + 0.j],
                     [0. + 0.j,  0. + 0.j,
                      -0.25859133+12.09860357j,  0. + 0.j],
                     [0. + 0.j,  0. + 0.j,
                      0. + 0.j, -0.25859133-12.09860357j]])

L_0 = np.eye(2)
S_f = np.array([[100, 0], [0, 100]])
tstep = 0.1
sigma_11 = 0.3
sigma_22 = 0.4
quadProc = None

def S_xr(omega, Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j):
    h_x = np.real(np.linalg.multi_dot(
        [Phi, np.linalg.inv(-1j*omega*np.linalg.inv(l_mat)+np.eye(np.shape(l_mat)[0])), Phi.T]))  # Taking only the real value. Check again!!!

    ans = np.exp(1j*omega*t) * np.linalg.multi_dot([np.conjugate(h_x), s_f, h_x.T])
    return np.real(ans[i][j])


def S_xc(omega, Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j):
    h_x = np.real(np.linalg.multi_dot(
        [Phi, np.linalg.inv(-1j*omega*np.linalg.inv(l_mat)+np.eye(np.shape(l_mat)[0])), Phi.T]))  # Taking only the real value. Check again!!!

    ans = np.exp(1j*omega*t) * np.linalg.multi_dot([np.conjugate(h_x), s_f, h_x.T])
    return np.imag(ans[i][j])

def quadWrapper(S_x, Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j):
    return S_x, quad(S_x, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j), limit=10_000)

def R_x(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j):
    args = [(S_xr, Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j), (S_xc, Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j)]
    results = None

    def callback(n):
        nonlocal results
        results = n

    quadProc.starmap_async(func=quadWrapper, iterable=args, callback=callback).wait()

    for f, i in results:
        if f == S_xr:
            real_integral = i
        else:
            imag_integral = i

    return real_integral[0]+1j*imag_integral[0]


def R_final(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t):
    return np.array([[R_x(Phi, l_mat, s_f, t, i, j) for j in range(2)] for i in range(2)])


def cov_p(Phi, l_mat, s_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, N_p):
    global quadProc
    with Pool() as quadProc:
        ans = np.zeros([N_p, N_p, 2, 2], dtype=complex)
        for i in range(N_p):
            for j in range(N_p):
                ans[i][j] = np.linalg.multi_dot([L_0, R_final(
                    Phi, l_mat, s_f, (i-j)*tstep), L_0.T])+np.array([[sigma_11, 0], [0, sigma_22]])*(i==j)

    return ans.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(2*N_p, -1)

import time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    print(cov_p(phi, lamb_mat, S_f, sigma_11, sigma_22, 10))
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.2f}s')
```

Comment: The reason why it's taking days is that this is just a single evaluation of cov_p. I use cov_p along with a similar function which returns a matrix which is four times as large, and some other functions to generate a master function. A single evaluation of that master function is taking around 5 minutes. I am now trying to minimize that master function in all 16 variables. That's what's troubling me.

Comment: I'll try your version of the code in some time and report to you the results.

Comment: @ShakirRather If each invocation of *cov_p()* is not reliant on previous invocations then you could run that as a subprocess. Depending on your hardware, that could make a huge difference

Comment: I am basically minimizing a function (which calls cov_p) using scipy.optimize.minimize. So, every time it performs an evaluation and gradient descent, it  invokes cov_p. I don't think that can be subdivided into processes